# Apache WebDAV: no authentification

Tags: mac-osx, apache-2.4, webdav

I am trying to setup an Apache WebDAV server, however I am encountering 
problems presumably due to some misconfigurations.

My underlying host is running Mac OS X Yosemite and Apache works fine,
serving websites both for `localhost` and `localhost/~www`. 
The later is an other user I created.

I would like to provide a WebDAV service in that user-directory.

Therefore I've included the configuration file `httpd-dav.conf` in `httpd.conf` and I added the module `mod_dav` via the `LoadModule` directive.

My `httpd-dav.conf` looks like this:

```
 17 DavLockDB /Users/www/DAV/
 18 
 19 <Directory /Users/www/Sites/dav>
 20   Require all granted
 21   Dav On
 22 
 23   AuthType Basic
 24   AuthName e2TeamMember
 25   AuthUserFile "/Users/www/DAV/.passwd.dav"
 26 
 27   <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
 28     Require user admin
 29   </LimitExcept>
 30 </Directory>
```

I presume that by setting `Require all granted` I allow (read)access to anybody .

So how do I grant access only to users with a password?

The permissions to `/dav` are:

```
*drwxr-xr-x+ 3 nobody  nobody*
```